# Do I need to improve my Questions and Answers?

Tags: discussion

Some of my questions and answers do not have any up or downvotes. Do my questions and answers need to be improved or has no one seen them? By looking at my profile page, I see that some of my posts seem to have not received much attention.

Comment: Well, in SO, 9 out of your 11 questions, and 1 out of your 4 answers, have a positive score. This makes a total of 10 out of 15 posts. It's not that bad.

Comment: Would you like me to downvote some for you? ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland, Only if you send a dollar to my Paypal account per downvote! (^u^)

Comment: So I should *get* a dollar for an upvote then? Cool - invoice is on its way ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland, actually, everyone that answered my question each pays you a dollar! (^o^).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why not?**
As far I understood, you have posted [4 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2354783/devyn-collier-johnson?tab=answers) and got a total of 1 upvote and none of them were accepted.
And the number of upvotes and downvotes won't always depends on how popular your post was!! So you can skip the your doubts on lack of 'attention' on your posts.
I normally cast an upvote or downvote after checking the question well and if it doesn't demand one, I will simple leave it (*Its not a must to leave a vote on each post visited*). That can be the reason..

Well, I don't think you need to work on your questions anymore if they are solved. Also many of them have votes too ( *9/11 is a pretty good ratio,isn't it*?), I can't see any issue with your questions !

Your answers haven't convinced the OPs yet, and many of them seems like just comments to me. If you are sure that you can improve them..go ahead. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

My rule of thumb: If you feel you have to ask about improving, then you should at least try to improve.

Comment: I love this rule of thumb. I will try follow that rule. Mahalo.

Answer (score 3):

> > Do my questions and answers need to be improved?

Two of your questions did not receive upvotes:

- The problem with the [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385555/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-javascript-functions-per-html-file) was a typo. Since the future site visitors are unlikely to have the same typo in the same code, the question will probably not benefit others.
- The [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353521/motif-widgets-for-python3) almost sounds like a "Google it for me?" type of question. I am not familiar with the subject matter, so perhaps there are reasons that this information is only available here. However, to my eyes it seems that the answer could have been found via a search engine.

You received answers to both questions, so I would not recommend changing them now. For future reference, the questions most likely to receive upvotes are the ones that are most likely to help a broad audience.

> ...or has no one seen them?

At the time of this writing, the first question referenced above has received 50 views and the second has received 15. You can find the view counters in the sidebar.