# How can I improve my two Python3 questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, specific-question

I have two questions that recently received one down-vote each. They receive both up and down votes occasionally, but they now stand with a score of zero.

How can I improve them so they get more up-votes than down-votes?

- [Python3 Print First File Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399991/python3-print-first-file-line)
- [Making a Python3 Variable Using a Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908763/making-a-python3-variable-using-a-counter)

Comment: Include the Python code you tried before asking.

Comment: My concern is that you've asked [questions similar to this before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187835/do-i-need-to-improve-my-questions-and-answers), and after getting feedback from this, as well as reading the FAQ and Help, you should know to *include code* and *show what you've tried* before posting.  I've looked through your questions, and maybe one, two tops, show any real effort.

Comment: Shame on you @CodyGray, "two two Python3 questions" :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to show that you have at least attempted to solve the question yourself. As it stands, your questions are thinly veiled gimme-teh-codez questions, mere specifications of functionality desired.

Even if you didn't manage to write any code, sharing your *research* and how that failed to solve your problem would help us help you much better, and makes your question much more valuable to future visitors.

Quoting from the Stack Overflow [How to Ask help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer *before* asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!